# Use API response in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I'm trying to display a response from an API in a table. The API returns some information about arriving ships. So far I can only get it to display a response, I'm not sure if I'm on the correct track.

```
<script>
  fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
</script>
```

I then get the following response in the form of an array(s) in console:

```
0:
 ETA: "2018-09-27T19:00:00"
 MMSI: "31136700"
1:
 ETA: "2018-09-27T20:00:00"
 MMSI: "42386700"
```

I've been trying to get that data and display it in a table like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>MMSI</th>
   <th>ETA</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Ship 1 mmsi response</td>
    <td>Eta response 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Ship 2 mmsi response</td>
    <td>Eta response 2</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried different ways, but still haven't figured out how to display it properly, any tips?

Comment: Can you give a hint about the ways you have tried and supply woth the snippets? Welcome, btw.

Answer (score 0):

once you got response data use below code to appned new `tr` in table
im using jquery here.

```
for(i = 0;i<= json.length; i++){
  var data1 = json.ETA , data2 = json.MMSI ;
  $('table> tbody').append('<tr><td>'+  data1 +' </td><td> '+  data2 +' </td></tr>');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to the tbody:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>MMSI</th>
   <th>ETA</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="table-rows">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can populate it:

```
// Sample data - you will use your api here
let mockedData = [
    {
        ETA: 1,
        MMSI: 2
    },
    {
        ETA: 3,
        MMSI: 4
    },
    {
        ETA: 5,
        MMSI: 6
    }  
]

document.getElementById('table-rows').innerHTML = mockedData.map((item) => {
     return '<tr><td>' + item.ETA + '</td><td>' + item.MMSI + '</td></tr>'
}).join('');
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pc4yed12/4/

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I implement the API data though? If I do it like this, it just displays the values as whatever I've typed, and not the data from the api response.

Comment: In your second then clause, insert supplied snippet but replace mockedData with your json variable